# abstract classes, inheritance, best way to do programm with figures

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class FiguraProba
{

  public abstract class Figura {
    public abstract double pole();
    public abstract double obwod();
  }

  public abstract class Czworokat extends Figura {
    public double obwod(double bok1, double bok2, double bok3, double bok4)
    {
        return (bok1+bok2+bok3+bok4);
    }

    public abstract double pole();
  }

  public class Kwadrat extends Czworokat {

    double bok1;

    public Kwadrat(double bokPodany)
    {
        bok1=bokPodany;
    }

    public double pole(double bok1) {
        return bok1*bok1;
    }
  }

  public class Prostokat extends Czworokat {

    double bok1, bok2;

    public Prostokat(double bokPodany1, double bokPodany2)
    {
        bok1=bokPodany1;
        bok2=bokPodany2;
    }
    public double pole(double bok1, double bok2) {
        return bok1*bok2;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[] )
  {
    //System.out.println(Math.sin(90*(Math.PI/180)));
  }
}
```

I apologize for my English and using English variable names. My goal is: I have object f.e squareExample with side 5. I want to call function to compute area from class square and call function perimeter from class quadrange to compute perimeter. Is it possible?
Compilator says: "FiguraProba.Prostokat is not abstract and does not ovveride abstract method pole() in FiguraProba.Czworokat." I understand the error but I dont know how to work out the error to achieve the goal.

Sorry for using code variables and classes in a foreign language. Here is the explanation what all the words mean:
figura - figure
kwadrat - square 
czworokat - quadrangle
prostokat - rectangle
pole - area
obwod - perimeter
bok - side

Comment: You are not overriding the `pole` method correctly. If you define no arguments in the `abstract` class, then you are not allowed to ignore that. Your class Prostokat and Kwadrat are classes capable of having an instance. Therefore you are obligated to implement the `pole` method per contract you have (the `extend` usage).

Comment: Does my answer help you @PoorGuy ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be the following:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class FiguraProba
{

  public abstract class Figura {

    public abstract double pole();
    public abstract double obwod();
  }

  public abstract class Czworokat extends Figura {
    public double obwod(double bok1, double bok2, double bok3, double bok4)
    {
        return (bok1+bok2+bok3+bok4);
    }

    public abstract double pole();
  }

  public class Kwadrat extends Czworokat {

    double bok1;
    public Kwadrat(double bokPodany)
    {
        bok1=bokPodany;
    }

    // Method without any arguments like the Figura class
    // When you extend an abstract class, you have to 
    // implement the exact method with the exact number of arguments
    // Of course you are obligated only if you can create an instance 
    // of that object. The perfect example when you are not obligated to 
    // implement a method is class Czworokat. Czworokat is not 
    // obligated, because you can not create an instance out of it.
    public double pole() {
        return bok1*bok1;
    }
  }

  public class Prostokat extends Czworokat {
    double bok1, bok2;

    public Prostokat(double bokPodany1, double bokPodany2)
    {
        bok1=bokPodany1;
        bok2=bokPodany2;
    }

    // Same logic applies here.
    // When you extend an abstract class, you have to 
    // implement the exact method with the exact number of arguments
    // Of course you are obligated only if you can create an instance 
    // of that object. The perfect example when you are not obligated to 
    // implement a method is class Czworokat. Czworokat is not 
    // obligated, because you can not create an instance out of it.
    public double pole() {
        return bok1*bok2;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[] )
  {
    //System.out.println(Math.sin(90*(Math.PI/180)));
  }
}
```

This would be what you want in case you would only use the classes properties and return the value on behalf of that. If you do want the `pole` methods with one and two arguments (like you have it in the code), then you would still need to remove the abstract `pole` method OR you would need to implement that exact method with ZERO arguments.

You can not breach the contract by NOT implementing `pole` with no arguments. If you need a deeper understanding about `abstract` classes, then I would suggest you to take a look at the official Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding a method from abstract class you have to write it exacly what it looks like in interface. So your method should have the same name and the same arguments.

In other worlds, you have a method with signature double pole(double bok1), but you still have to override method dobule pole();